# What does functionname("#{....}") inside a onclick attribute of a button mean?

Tags: javascript, xml, xhtml

Its an XHTML page I'm going through. Inside the `onclick` attribute of a button, a JavaScript function is being called. What does the expression "#{...}" in the function parameter mean? (By ... I mean some variable of a class being referred to).

Following line is the code I'm referring to in the XHTML page. What do they mean with # here..

```
<input type="button" onclick="download("#{Hitlistbean.bean},#{Hitlist1.bean},...")">
```

Comment: On its own, they're just characters in a string -- though, the dual use of double-quotes isn't valid. The `#{...}` syntax is often associated with [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), used as an alternative to concatenation, and there's likely a template engine involved that evaluates and replaces them.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link for "interpolation." Should be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation.

Comment: Check the download function and you should know

Comment: Go ask the guy who wrote it.

Comment: Is this maybe JSF (Java Server Faces)? The word "Hitlistbean.bean" makes it look like Java.

Comment: cw24 yes it is jsf.. Can u explain?